# MATLAB: Automatic assigning of matrix element indices

Tags: matlab

I am currently in the process of writing a custom function to compute the RREF of a given `m x n` matrix. Since I am a complete newbie to MATLAB, I thought it would be a good idea to sample the built-in `rref()` function.

While examining the part of code that found "the value and index of largest element in the remainder" of the leading column, I had that:

```
 [p,k] = max(abs(A(i:m,j)))
```

where `m` is the number of rows of the matrix, and `i=j=1`.

I understand that `max(abs(A(i:m,j)))` gives you the value of the largest element in the leading column - a single scalar answer. However, I **cannot** understand why it manages to assign *two* values to `[p,k]`, with `k`being the index number for `p`. could someone please be kind enough to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k is the position in your vector where the maximum value is.

For instance, assume we use the vector `[1,2,5,2,1]`. There the max value is 5. This value is at the third position in the vector. So `[p,k] = max([1,2,5,2,1]);`will return `p=5` and `k=3`.

The function will assing values depending on how you call it.

```
p = max(...
```

will assign only `p`

```
[p,k] = max(...
```

will assign `p` and `k`.

Comment: Oh, I understand that `k` is the position index, I just don't understand how a function with a single value output can assign two values.

Comment: Updated answer. This is not a function with a single value output. The function can return multiple values.

Comment: Wow, I was dumb. Read your answer, looked at the help page for the `max()` function, and voilà... Thanks for your help! :P